# *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I got the above error when trying to launch my app second time. First time I got it properly. But when I try to select the tableview, I am getting the error. please help me

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier =CELL_IDENTIFIER_STRING;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff);

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Please include the rest of the error message. There's usually another line that gives you the details of which assertion failed.

Comment: Also, the code in your question won't compile as it is missing a closing brace in the if statement. Make sure your actual code is in the question

Comment: @jrturton actually there is brace too for if statement. I missed it while copying it to this page. I am getting the error as               unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: What selector? Instance of what? Nobody can help you unless you provide these details. Also, please update the question with your correct code, there is an edit link on there for this purpose.

Comment: Unrecognised selector sent to instance will also show you the class that was sent the message, and the message it didn't recognise, such as `[NSString wibbleWobble]`. This would show if you called `wibbleWobble` on an NSString.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

////// ***************************
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
//////     *****************************

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff);

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Comment: See his comment above, he clarified that missing braces was just a typo. And please change your username , it feels like I am commenting to a bot Sorry :P